# Dc.js charts interactivity fails when charts are dynamically added by users.Pls see description for more details

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am looking for a way to get Dc.js charts to be added to a dashboard by user choice of chart in a palette.
End of the day I want the user to be able to do 2 things.
Part 1: User should be able to select and add various charts from charts palette into a dashboard by selecting respective target variable(x,y fields) which are nothing but fields in csv, one by one for each chart.
 
Part 2 : These charts  which form a kind of dashboard should be reactive or interactive(change in one chart reflects change in all other charts) which is not the case now.
I have already achieved the 1st part by below code , but the main challenge is 2nd part. Charts are no more coordinated visualizations(by change of a pie in one chart , other charts do not reflect the change)
I have added all charts in 1 function with a switch case statement. Everything works fine up to adding the charts to the dashboard or respective div but this does not make the charts reactive(click on one chart does not affect other charts).
Little note about the below code and its intentions.
-I am dynamically creating div’s and assigning ids.
-here num in my function is a random number assigned in calling function to make sure there are no duplicate divs with same id.
-Targetvar is a field chosen by the user.
-arrayofobject is the actual data.
-ctype is the charttype chosen by user.I have declared 2 charts(pie and row) for example sake.Their are more charts in the palette for user to choose.
Please let me know what change I need to make to get charts be reactive.

```
function charts_all(targetvar1,arrayOfObject,num,ctype){
        var selname="#divid"+num;

        switch(ctype){
        case "pie":

            var SevPieChart=dc.pieChart(selname);
            data=arrayOfObject;

            var ndx = crossfilter(data);
            var all = ndx.groupAll();

            var targetvariable1=targetvar1;

            var SevDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d[targetvariable1]; })
            ;

            var Sevgroup=SevDim.group();
            SevPieChart
                .height(400)
                .width(1200)//1200
                .radius(150)
                .innerRadius(20)
                .dimension(SevDim)
                .group(Sevgroup)
                .transitionDuration(1000)
                .legend(dc.legend().x(950).y(40)) //LEGEND CODE x=950
                .externalLabels(0)
                .renderLabel(true)
                .label(function(d) { return d.key +" (" + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100) + "%)"; })
                .title(function(d){return d.Sevgroup;});
                //dc.renderAll();
                alldefault();
            break;

        case "row":

            var Rowchart = dc.rowChart(selname);

            data=arrayOfObject;


            var ndx = crossfilter(data);
            var all = ndx.groupAll();


            var targetvariable1=targetvar1;

            var SaDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d[targetvariable1]; })
            ; 
            var SAgroup=SaDim.group();


            Rowchart
                .width(1000)
                  .height(1000)
                 .dimension(SaDim)
                 .group(SAgroup)
                 .renderLabel(true)
                 .label(function(d) { return d.key+" (" + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100) + "%)"; })
                 .data(function(group){ return group.top(40);})  ;        
                 //Rowchart.filter = function() {};

                //dc.renderAll();
                alldefault();

            break;

        default:


        }
        dc.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: You are defining a new Crossfilter for each chart. You need to use just one Crossfilter and create all of your dimensions and groups from it.

Comment: Thanks Ethen for your reply.The problem persists.I replaced these lines outside the switch function .Something like this charts_all(targetvar1,arrayOfObject,num,ctype){
   var selname="#divid"+num;
   data=arrayOfObject;
   var ndx = crossfilter(data);
   var all = ndx.groupAll();<br> switch(ctype){
        case "pie":

            var SevPieChart=dc.pieChart(selname);

            var targetvariable1=targetvar1;

            var SevDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d[targetvariable1]; })
            ;

Comment: It doesn't need to be outside the switch, it needs to be outside the whole function so that the same Crossfilter object is used every time you call that function :)

Comment: Its not working Ethen.I removed crossfilter declarations from function and initialized it in calling function like the code below.Note ndx and all variables are removed from called function now . <code>function insertChart(targetvar1,arrayOfObject,num,charttype){
 var newArr;
 

      data=arrayOfObject;
      var ndx = crossfilter(data);
   var all = ndx.groupAll();
   
      charts_all(targetvar1,data,num,charttype,ndx,all);'<code>

Comment: Hi Mohan, please create a working example on jsfiddle or a similar site and I’ll be happy to get it working for you. You are still calling “crossfilter(data)” inside the “insertChart” function as far as I can see, which is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi Ethen, Here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/vmksharma/5dcp84Lr/51/.
Pls click "Chart Wizard" button.The button for some reason gets inserted in the bottom of page.Might be issue with css.So pls scroll to find the button.

I have 3 function:                                         
chartconfirm():- Inserts layout 
insertChart() :- Cross filter is initialized here(upon your advise).
charts_all() :-This function contains dc.js code for 3 charts.For some reason this part is not working on jsfiddle(Error I get:Uncaught TypeError: _listeners.preRender is not a function)

Comment: Ethen,I have posted js fiddle link in previous comment.Could not add few points in previous comments due to SO limitation.The code published on fiddle does not work for some reason,but the code works fine outside jsfiddler.And I had to add all the code including JS part in HTML as fiddler was failing to recognize functions in JS window.

Comment: Hi Mohan, I don't understand how to run this. Can you please get it working somewhere as a minimal example? Get rid of everything except inserting 2 charts by calling a function :) Cheers, Ethan

Comment: Hi Ethen, Unfortunately, I could not make it work on jsfiddle .So giving you the the app link http://sampleviz.mybluemix.net/FrontPage/Login.php

Credentials to be used

email :user@sampleviz.com
password : user123

Click on button "click to view models" .

Here I have uploaded a sample data file for you

Keep clicking on  button "click to view models" or similar till you get a chance to select respective charts.Try inserting at least 2 charts to see how it works.I have tried and interactivity does not work.You can use "Inspect" to debug.Pls let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: The problem lies in these 3 function on customdash file and scriptfunc.js: chartconfirm(),insertChart() and charts_all().Thanks in advance for your help.